# Why my strings are not going to be XOR?

Tags: c++, string, operator-keyword, xor

I want to encrypt the string of password entered by user, and then print it on screen. Also recover the original password and then print it on screen too. But XOR operator is not working with strings. How can I manipulate it?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string pass;
  string enc="akdhigfohre";
  string x;


   cout<<"Enter new password:  ";
   cin>>pass;
   cout<<"\n\nYour New Password is:" << pass<<endl;

   x=pass^enc;
   cout<<"\n\nEncrypted Version: "<<x;

   x=x^enc;
   cout<<"\n\nRecovred Password:  "<<x;

   system("pause");



}
```

Comment: you could sprit your string into characters, xor each individual character, and then combine them into new string

Comment: Thanks sir. How can I split the characters? please tell the code.

Comment: Just `for(char c: pass) { ... }`

Comment: it will be something like `for (int i = 0; i<x.length;i++) {newPass+= x[i]^enc[i%enc.length]; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another try on the code base of the question ,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string pass;
  string enc="akdhigfohre";
  string x = "";
  string y = "";

   cout<<"Enter new password:  ";
   cin>>pass;
   cout<<"\n\nYour New Password is:" << pass<<endl;

   for(size_t i = 0; i < pass.size(); ++i){
     x += pass.at(i)^enc.at(i%enc.size());
   }
   cout<<"\n\nEncrypted Version: "<<x;

   for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i){
     y += x.at(i)^enc.at(i%enc.size());
   }

   cout<<"\n\nRecovred Password:  "<<y;

   system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a solution that can solve your problem. Hope it will be helpful for you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include<iostream>
using std::string;

string XOR(string value,string key)
{
    string retval(value);

    short unsigned int klen=key.length();
    short unsigned int vlen=value.length();
    short unsigned int k=0;
    short unsigned int v=0;

    for(v;v<vlen;v++)
    {
        retval[v]=value[v]^key[k];
        k=(++k<klen?k:0);
    }

    return retval;
}

int main()
{
    std::string value("Phuc Nguyen");
    std::string key("akdhigfohre");

    std::cout<<"Plain text: "<<value<<"\n\n";
    value=XOR(value,key);
    std::cout<<"Cipher text: "<<value<<"\n\n";
    value=XOR(value,key);
    std::cout<<"Decrypted text: "<<value<<std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I will in future. but now i have reputation<15.